# What do the remotes in the output of git log mean?

Tags: git, github, cygwin

Yet another dawn, yet another day spent trying to learn the shockingly counter-intuitive, jargon-infested mess that is Git. When I run the command `git log` on my local development server, I get the following output:

```
$ git log
commit 07cfffea573a70a59b2be7a6ff8d7dee3e831e (HEAD -> master, live/master)
Author: My Name <example@hotmail.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 6 17:02:16 2020 +0000

    manual changes to functions.php permissions

commit 3f507d8211be744b1c5a997c81d13b77d968be (central/master)
Author: My Name <example@hotmail.com>
Date:   Thu Mar 12 00:14:22 2020 +0000

    Contact Form 7 update

commit 41c64ed4fbde1924557e7886901ab8078d088a
Author: My Name <example@hotmail.com>
Date:   Wed Mar 11 19:11:53 2020 +0000

    Added PHP error log for Contact Form 7
```

In simple terms, what exactly are those remotes there signifying? No question that I've found seems to have answered this yet, and it took one look at `man git log` to know it wasn't written for a Git beginner.

To me, the output seems to be saying that those remotes are currently stuck on the respective commits that they appear besides, but I know this can't be the case because I've already pushed the latest commit from `live` directly to `central` (and confirmed on Github that the changes were made) and yet `central` is still shown next to the old commit.

What exactly do the remotes here mean?

Comment: Did you push "live" to "central" from the same repository in which you are viewing the log?

Comment: @GregBurghardt No, I pushed to `central` from `live` and then pulled the changes from `central` to my local repo, where I ran `git log`. If both `live` and `central` match in content, shouldn't pulling from either repository have the same difference?

Comment: You will need to pull from central if you didn't push to central from your current repository.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: the answer to your commentary question:

> Does it mean that I have to fetch/pull from both my remotes to keep my local repository up to date, even if the content of the two remotes is the same (due to pushing the changes of one to the other)?

is "yes, you must run `git fetch` to each remote".  You might want to define a *group* of remotes and/or run `git remote update`, which runs `git fetch` to all remotes.  Or, `git fetch --all` also updates from all remotes.  (The group stuff gives you much greater control; you can use `git remote update group` to update a specific group of remotes.)

#### Long

To make sense of this stuff, you need to realize that:

- A Git repository stores commits (and other Git objects) in one database—usually the big one—and some set of names, such as branch names, tag names, and remote-tracking names, in a second (usually much smaller) database.
- Commits are uniquely numbered by their hash IDs, but all Gits (all Git repositories, that is) that have the same commit always use the same hash ID for all the commits that are 100% identical in those two Gits.
- Branch names—but not any other names—have a special property: they always, by definition, contain the raw hash ID of the *last* commit that is part of that branch.
- To make all of the above work, when you get "on" a branch and then make a *new* commit, Git automatically replaces the stored hash ID in the branch name with the hash ID of the newly-created commit (which has a hash ID that has never appeared in your own Git repository before, and won't be in any *other* Git repository either, but which every future Git that gets that commit will agree is *the* hash ID for *that* commit).
- In general—there are some exceptions, but we'll leave those aside for now—we only ever *add* new commits to a repository.  This makes it easier to think about the various cases, so it's a helpful simplification.

Then, to that we add this:

- Each Git repository is normally independent of any other Git repository.
- Occasionally, though, you'll connect one Git to another Git.  When you do, one Git will present some or all of its names to the other Git.  These are the `fetch` and `push` operations.  One Git will offer to the other Git some set of commits that one of the two doesn't have yet:

  - For `git fetch`, the other Git lists its names and hash IDs, and your Git *gets* commits it doesn't have yet but wants / needs.
  - For `git push`, your Git lists hash IDs, and the other Git takes those if it needs them.  Then your Git asks politely (regular push) or commands (force-push) the other Git to set some of *its* name(s) to some hash ID(s).  Typically those are branch names: we have a new commit, or maybe *n* new commits, for branch `master` or branch `develop` or whatever, so we send them over, then ask them to update *their* `master` or `develop` or whatever.

The *remote-tracking names*, like `origin/master`, `central/master`, `live/master`, and so on are *your* Git's memory of some *other* Git's *branch* names.  These memories can only be updated when your Git contacts their Git.  For internal reasons, your Git only updates the specific names that you `git push`, when you `git push`; but `git fetch` by default updates everything, unless you tell it some specific set of names it should update.

If there is only one other Git that you ever contact and they never update their names except by your commands, your Git always has the right information.  That's the common case with a private GitHub storage-repo for your own personal repository, for instance: nobody else ever *adds* to it.  It only gets *new* commits from you.  So your `git fetch` never really has to do any work: their branch names are always a result of some earlier `git push` of yours.

If other people can update the other Git (or Gits, plural), though, you'll need to run `git fetch` to contact each other Git and find out what new commit(s) have been added to their branch(es) since the last contact your particular Git made to that particular Git.  Your `git fetch remote` will obtain the new commits—with their unique, but common-across-all-Gits, hash IDs—from that other Git and then update your `remote/branchname` remote-tracking branch or branches as appropriate.

If you have remotes `alice` and `barney` and run `git fetch alice`, you'll get any new commits, then update all your `alice/*` names.  A subsequent `git fetch barney` might not actually get any new commits—maybe you already got them from `alice` for instance—but will then update all your `barney/*` names.

#### It *is* possible to drop commits from branches

Note that one can drop a commit from a branch using `git branch -f` or `git reset`.  That is, given something like:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
```

where the name `master` identifies the commit whose hash is `H`, and commit `H` leads back to commit `G` and so on, we can `git checkout master; git reset --hard HEAD~1` to shove `H` out of the way:

```
            H   [abandoned]
           /
... <-F <-G   <-- master
```

Commit `H` remains in this repository for a at least a little while—how long, depends on many other factors we won't go into here—but now `master` identifies commit `G` instead of commit `H`.

If *this* Git repository is someone else's remote—e.g., if we're `alice` at the moment—and you already got commit `H` from `alice` so that your `alice/master` names commit `H`, then when you run:

```
git fetch alice
```

you'll see that your `alice/master` is *force-updated*.  This tells you that Alice did something that got rid of a commit.  You'll still have commit `H` in *your* repository too, for a while; you may or may not be able to find it easily some way; but your `alice/master` is *also* now retracted by one commit, to identify commit `G` too.

#### Tags don't fit this pattern

Tag names in Git *should* never move.  That's a constraint we place on human beings, who don't always obey.  When and whether your Git updates a tag name that your Git remembers is a little tricky.  Tags are different from branches in two ways: first, they're not *supposed* to move, unlike branch names; and second, your Git will often just copy some other Git's tag name to your Git, without asking and without this kind of fancy remote-tracking stuff.  There's no `alice/v1.2`, there's just tag `v1.2`.

If tags are never deleted and never move, you'll never have to worry about any of this: you either have a tag, and it's right, or you just don't have it yet, and you can get it from any other Git.

Comment: Thanks for going further than I went ! One small comment : when you write “a Git”, “your Git”, “Gits”, etc. what you really mean is “your local Git repository”, “several Git repositories”, etc. I think it can be confusing to use Git as a noun like that (because it could also mean “your local Git software” and “the remote Git software”). Those are two different concepts and should not be mixed in my opinion (especially when explaining stuff to beginners). “Git” is only ever used in the official documentation as the name of the software.

Comment: @philb: True, I'll consider expanding this a bit in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> In simple terms, what exactly are those remotes there signifying?

The annotations next to the commits in the output of `git log` always correspond to your **local** "refs" (i.e. branches or tags). Here, `live/master` and `central/master` are *remote-tracking* branches; you can list those using `git branch --remote` (or `-r` for short).

Remote-tracking branches are local references, they are updated when you:

1. push a change to the corresponding branch on the respective remote, i.e. `git push central master` should push the new changes on the currently checked out branch to the `master` branch on the `central` remote, and update `refs/remotes/central/master` to point to the head of the current branch
2. fetch a remote. i.e. `git fetch central master` would fetch the `master` branch on the `central` remote and update `refs/remotes/central/master`. Similarly, `git fetch central` would fetch all branches on the `central` remote. And since `git pull` does `git fetch` under the hood, remote-tracking branches are also updated when pulling.

---

Regarding the Git man pages: it's true that some are not easy to read for beginners. I recommend that you start with these resources:

- [The Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)
- [The Atlassian Git tutorials](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials)
- The [Tower Git tutorial](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/basics/what-is-version-control)

Some pages from the official documentation:

- [the `git(1)` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git) **just reading this should help you understand the rest of the manpages a little bit better**
- [`gitglossary`, a glossary of common terms in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary)
- [The Git Users' manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual)
- [`gittutorial`, a small official tutorial](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)

Comment: But in practical terms, what does that actually mean? Does it mean that I have to fetch/pull from *both* my remotes to keep my local repository up to date, even if the content of the two remotes is the same (due to pushing the changes of one to the other)?